# How do I open and read a file in C?

Tags: formatting, fread

I'm starting a new program and one of the first steps is to read a file that was written in a previous program. The program fails to run between the `fseek()` line and the `fread()` line, I get the following error:

```
debug assertion failed
expression:(stream!=NULL)
```

My code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int m = 0;
    char stream[20];
    FILE *fp;

    /* opens a file which had data written into it in a previous program */
    fp = fopen("codetree.bin", "r");

    /* makes sure the file pointer is set at the beginning of the file */
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    m = sizeof(stream);
    fread(&stream, m, 1, fp);
    /* ... */
}
```

If I add the following lines to check whether fopen was successful or not:

```
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("fopen() error...%s\n", strerror(errno)); 
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
 no such file or directory exists
```

What am I overlooking or missing in my code?

Comment: What is the problem you observe here?

Comment: it says that the "debug assertion failed" and that "expresssion:(stream!=NULL)" after that it aborts running the code.

Comment: Your program cannot open `codetree.bin` (perhaps it is looking in the wrong place?). You should add code to check that `fp != NULL` after the `fopen()`, before proceeding with the rest of your code.

Comment: ah. I added that line of code and that is indeed the problem. Thankyou for the help.

Comment: hmm. so when i added the following line                             //if( fp==NULL)
printf("fopen() error...%s\n", strerror(errno)); //                   it said that "no such file or directory exists". I have codetree.bin in my source files, is that the wrong place?

Comment: The current directory when your program runs is probably some other directory, and not your source file directory. It is probably running in the directory where your executable is created (for example, in Visual Studio, look for a `Debug` subdirectory).

Comment: so the file needs to be in the debug subdirectory?

Comment: Ask yourself: "How do the computer will know where is located the file you want to open?" You are telling to fopen to open a file without giving any path, so the program can only assume the file should be in the same directory where the program is running.  I recommend you to read the book "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan & Ritchie.  It is short, concise and it explains the basic of I/O in C.

Comment: You have to reach the file through the relative path from your executable. For example:
- Executable at Project/Debug/prog.exe
- File at Project/Assets/codetree.bin
- You read from "../Assets/codetree.bin" (.. is the notation for parent folder)